# Reverse this number :$99(x-z)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Reverse this number $99(x-z)$.In which $99(x-z)$ is a three digit number. "Reverse" here means to reverse the digits, so $123\to 321$ and $565\to 565$

I need to reverse this number but can't find out if mathematically.Taking examples I have come to know that the reverse of the given number is $99(11-x+z)$. But how I prove it mathematically. Please help me.

Comment: How do you define "reverse"? And why is the reverse of the number the number itself?

Comment: What does it mean to reverse a number?  If I take $x=7,z=4$  I see $99\times (7-4)=297$.  In what sense is the reverse of $297$ itself?

Comment: Is it $(z-x)66$?

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity.  Show an example of what you are talking about.  If you have a conjectured result, show some examples that illustrate it.

Comment: @Lovsovs  the question is updated.

Comment: I disagree with the closure.  It is not well stated, but for $x=7, z=4$ we have $99(x-z)=297$ and OP wants to get $792$.  OP has noted that $99(11-7+4)=792$ and wants help to prove the general formula.

Comment: @RossMillikan The problem was recently updated; the formula made no sense before.

Comment: @Théophile:  then please vote to reopen.  It is hard to find enough votes for that

Comment: Let $x-z=k\lt 10$, then if we express $99k=(100-1)k=100k-k$ in digits it is $(k-1)9(10-k)$ which you can see if you do the subtraction.  The reverse is then $(10-k)9(k-1)$ and you want $99k'=(10-k)9(k-1)$.  This yields $k'=11-k$

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The earlier version of the problem made no sense, but the edited version does.

Comment: I slightly rephrased the definition of "reverse" and have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, let's write $x-z=k+1$. In order for $99(k+1)$ to be a three-digit number, we need $1\le k\le9$.  Note that

$$99(k+1)=100k+90+9-k=k\cdot10^2+9\cdot10^1 +(9-k)10^0$$

The key thing to notice here is that $1\le k\le9$ implies $0\le9-k\le8$, so $9-k$ is a single digit.  Then, reversing the digits, we have

$$(9-k)10^2+9\cdot10^1+k\cdot10^0=990-99k=99(11-(k+1))$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=x-z$.

Then there are just a few values that fit, 
$$y=(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$$

These give $11-y$ these values,

$$11-y=(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2)$$

Multiply all of these by $99$,

$$99y=(198,297,396,495,594,693,792,891)$$

$$99(11-y)=(891,792,693,594,495,396,297,198)$$

You can see than the second of each pair is a reversal of the first, and that each pair sums to $1089=11*99$.

You might want to include $y=1$, or not.